# foreach test if not already added

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I'd like to know how to add comparisons in a foreach and go to the next item.
I want this loop to go to the next data if the actual data test has already been added before or if its empty

```
foreach ($tracks as $i => $track) {
    $id[$i]=$track['id'];
    $title[$i]=$track['title'];
    $genre[$i]=$track['genre'];
    $artwork[$i]=$track['artwork_url'];
}
```

I thought about this but it doesn't work.

```
foreach ($tracks as $i => $track) {
     if (array_key_exists($track['id'],$id)){
        continue;
     }
     if (empty($track['artwork_url'])){
        continue;
     }
    $id[$i]=$track['id'];
    $title[$i]=$track['title'];
    $genre[$i]=$track['genre'];
    $artwork[$i]=$track['artwork_url'];
}
```

Thank you in advance for your friendly help :)

Comment: What is `$tracks`, what is the larger context here of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: What doesn't work about the code? Also what is `$id`?

Comment: *sidenote* Its not a good idea to separate your data into separate variables.

Comment: @Dan track comes from the parsing of a json file which regroups many songs. This foreach if used to fill in arrays in order to echo there lately, but there are many songs which are posted many times so I wanted to do a test during this foreach to eliminate the duplicates or the songs with no artwork.

Comment: It's for this website : http://electropose.fr/ / I'm a parsing a json file from soundcloud.

Comment: Post the results of `var_dump($tracks)`

Comment: Here's a small part of it : array(559) { [0]=> array(43) { ["kind"]=> string(5) "track" ["id"]=> int(155675361) ["created_at"]=> string(25) "2014/06/23 17:23:41 +0000" ["user_id"]=> int(267094) ["duration"]=> int(222375) ["commentable"]=> bool(true) ["state"]=> string(8) "finished" ["original_content_size"]=> int(58820624) ["sharing"]=> string(6) "public" ["tag_list"]=> string(115) ""Deep House" "Deep Hop" "Hip Pop" House "French Touch" Tropical Chill Flute Kygo Flume Darius Summer Beach Clichés" ["permalink"]=> string(9) "iwasafool" ["streamable"]=> bool(true) ["embeddable_by"]=> string(3)

Comment: the json file contains datas I don't want, so I use this foreach to select the data I want to use and order them in arrays with the same index so it's more easy to echo with a loop for. I've got the id/title/genre/artwork. Then I use a for to echo the different sounds !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$id` array stores values based on an index, not id; this should work, though:

```
if (in_array($track['id'], $id)) {
    continue;
}
```

This isn't very efficient, though for relatively small data sets the O(n) searches should still be manageable.

Alternatively, consider something like this:

```
$result = [];

foreach ($tracks as $track) {
    if (isset($result[$track['id']]) || empty($track['artwork_url'])) {
        continue;
    }

    $result[$track['id']] = array(
        'id' => $track['id'],
        'title' => $track['title'],
        'genre' => $track['genre'],
        'artwork' => $track['artwork_url'],
    );
}
```

Comment: With this solution, you have to make sure that `$track['id']` is unique.

Comment: @Sarke And isn't that what OP is trying to do with those `continue;` statements?

Comment: I usually avoid `in_array` unless I specifically need it, and in this case we are looking for a key not a value.  However, with the one assignment in your second code block, it doesn't need a check because it will simply overwrite it if it's the same id.  That's how I would do it.

Comment: @Sarke No, the value you're looking for isn't stored in the keys of `$id` but in the its values; ergo, `in_array()`.

Comment: @Sarke The check is needed if there's a difference between the first and last track of same id. I can't tell whether that's the case, so the safest assumption is to follow OP's logic.

Comment: Then why didn't you use `in_array` in your solution? :P

Comment: @Sarke You realise that I've given OP two solutions, right?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be

`if (array_key_exists($track['id'],$id))`

because you're passing it the value instead of the key.  The key is `$i`, so the second line should be

`if (array_key_exists($i,$id)){`

On a side note, I usually use

`if (isset($id[$i]))` or `if (!empty($id[$i]))`

because I find it more readable.

Comment: `isset` and `!empty` aren't the same things though. I think you've hit the answer right on though, simply [RTM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php).

Comment: I think your totally right, but I tried with your solution and it still doesn't filter :/

Comment: @DaveChen, yes, that's why I said "or" depending on what I need it to do.

Comment: Assuming that one starts with an empty `$id` array, at each pass `$id[$i]` will not have been defined so this code can never work.